# How to code a bash script to fill null fields of a text table

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I have a bash script that produces a table as output like this:

```
Name                 IP Address        IPv6 Address                     Address Source   Connection Type
Inferno              192.168.0.12      N/A                              DHCP             Ethernet 
VirgilioMarone       192.168.0.10      N/A                              DHCP             Ethernet 
RE305                192.168.0.2       N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi 
Google-Nest-Hub      192.168.0.100     N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi 
iPaddiG              192.168.0.216     N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi 
*                                      N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi 
Alighieri            192.168.0.13      N/A                              DHCP             Wi-FI
```

I need to identify an algorithm that receives the table above and puts "-" where the field is null like this (I don't replicate the other line only to simplify text):

```
Name              IP Address        IPv6 Address                     Address Source   Connection Type
   *              -                 N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi 5GHz
```

P.S. no tab between the text; only spaces.

Comment: Do you know the number of characters in each field?

Comment: Please, post the bash script, it could probably be done there.

Comment: Yes, it would be best to fix it in the source script, rather than trying to fix up the output.

Comment: If the first field is always 7 column, you can use `sed` with a regular expression that matches any 7 characters at the beginning of the line followed by a space, and replaces it with those 7 characters followed by `-`. Use a capture group to get the contents of the first field and copy it to the replacement.

Comment: - No, the number of characters of each fild changes dinamically.
- The bash script is the query result of a router command, I can't modify the firmware...or better I don't want spend energy to do it :)

Comment: You can use `awk`. When it reads the header line it can get the number of characters in the first field. Then it can use that to check if the next character after that in data rows is a space, and replace it with `-`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need the code :), I need to discuss about the algorithm to use, in this moment I have no idea how to find the place where put the dot.

Comment: Barman, your idea sounds good, I'll try to identify if in the same columns (index) of the header there is a character in the records above....

Comment: can fields contain spaces?

Comment: No, fields are without space, between each field there are 2 or more spaces.

Comment: hmmm, your sample data shows just a single space between the columns in the header record

Comment: Only beacause I am not the best ascii artist in the world :), the space/s between the fileds in the header is/are related to the records lenght of the fields below

Comment: the current data set looks like the first 2x columns are fixed-width @ 6 characters each plus a single space between columns 1 and 2 (per the single space in the header row); if this is not an accurate description of the incoming data then we need a better description and/or more realistic sample data

Comment: general algo: ignore first row, for all other rows find starting column for each field, maintain array of field #'s and starting positions (keep in mind may need to 'insert' new entry in array if previous line had a 'missing' field or two); use master list of fields/starting-positions to compare each line's field count and starting positions to determine what field is 'missing'; easily doable with `awk` and 2 passes through file (or one pass if storing entire file in memory so it can be processed a 2nd time)

Comment: Can you rely on the output being strictly columnar, so that the output for the third column, say, in a particular run is always at the same start offset (column 39 for "IPv6 Address" in the sample data) for this run, even if it might be a different column in a different run? So the spacing of the heading line is respected throughout the rest of the report?  It'll be a bit fiddly, but once you've determined the start point of each column heading, formatting the other lines appropriately with a dash in place of an empty field is doable using `"%-*s"` as a format component taking width and value.

Comment: You'll likely find some or all of the Awk functions `substr()`, `index()`, `match()` and `split()` useful in solving the "where does each column start" problem.

Comment: I would want to see the script that actually generates the first results - no need to jiggle with the result if this maybe fixed in the original script - can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first line to fetch the expected size of each column.

```sh
head -1 /path/to/file |
  grep -oE '[^ ]([^ ]| [^ ])* *  ' |
  awk '{print length($0)}'
```

- `head -1` keeps the first line only
- `grep -oE '[^ ]([^ ]| [^ ])* *  '` captures all strings that start with a non-whitespace character `[^ ]` followed by anything that does not have two consecutive spaces `([^ ]| [^ ])*` and end with a space sequence with at least two spaces `*`  ; beware of the exact characters in the regex otherwise it will simply not work
- `awk '{print length($0)}'` simply displays the length of each of these sequences

Please note that the last column is missing because it does not end with 2+ spaces. This is a good thing because I assume the last column should not be limited to a fixed width.

For your example it outputs:

```sh
21
18
33
17
```

Once you have this list, you can store it into an array, e.g.:

```sh
mapfile -t widths < <(head -1 /path/to/file |
  grep -oE '[^ ]([^ ]| [^ ])* *  ' |
  awk '{print length($0)}')
```

Then you can read every line and split it using the fixed width of each column:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  t=0;
  for x in "${widths[@]}"; do
    s=${line:$t:$x};
    if [[ "$s" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then
      printf %s "${s/ /-}";
    else
      printf -- %s "$s";
    fi;
    ((t+=x));
  done;
  s=${line:$t};
  if [ -z "$s" ]; then
    printf -- -\\n;
  else
    if [[ "$s" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then
      printf %s\\n "${s/ /-}";
    else
      printf -- %s\\n "$s";
    fi;
 fi;
done < /path/to/file
```

- `while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do ... done < /path/to/file` reads every line in the `$line` variable ; it is very important to read with the `-r` option so that escape sequences are not interpreted, and to set `IFS=` so that leading and trailing whitespaces are not trimmed ; the `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` bonus is a trick that fixes a limitation of `read` that returns false if the last line of the file does not end with a newline character
- `t` is the total number of characters read so far in that line
- `for x in "${widths[@]}"; do ... done` loops through the `widths` array computed before
- `s=${line:$t:$x}` fetches characters from index `t` to index `t+x`, in other words it **fetches one column from the line** and **keeps the trailing whitespace characters**, this is where the magic happens, because once you have it you’ve won
- `if [[ "$s" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then printf %s "${s/ /-}"; else printf -- %s "$s"; fi;` checks if the column if fully empty, in which case it calls `printf %s "${s/ /-}"` which outputs the string with the first character replaced by a hypen while keeping the field width intact (you can do the same with `printf -- "%-${x}s" -`) otherwise it prints the string as is `printf -- %s "$s"`, make sure to use `--` otherwise you will get errors if the string `"$s"` starts with a hypen
- `((t+=x))` advances the variable `t` so that the next column starts at the correct index
- and then `s=${line:$t}` gets the last column starting at index `t` until the end of the line, i.e. without a fixed width
- the print of the last column is pretty much the same as the other columns except we handle the case of an empty column (which cannot happen on previous columns) and we end the output with `\\n` in order to output the newline character

If everything went well, it should display:

```sh
Name                 IP Address        IPv6 Address                     Address Source   Connection Type
Inferno              192.168.0.12      N/A                              DHCP             Ethernet
VirgilioMarone       192.168.0.10      N/A                              DHCP             Ethernet
RE305                192.168.0.2       N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi
Google-Nest-Hub      192.168.0.100     N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi
iPaddiG              192.168.0.216     N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi
*                    -                 N/A                              DHCP             Wi-Fi
Alighieri            192.168.0.13      N/A                              DHCP             Wi-FI
```